# What is the definitive method for waiting for an ajax element to finish loading

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a google map container that is ajax loaded into the main page. I need to wait for the map container to have the proper size (say 100% width) in order for the map to present properly.

`$(document).ready` doesn't work, the size is not correct.

`window.onload` doesn't work either, likely because the container is ajax loaded, even with an event listener in the ajax function.

`jquery.load` doesn't work either.

This seems to be a general enough problem but sadly as I browse through the related questions I cannot find a satisfactory answer.

[Let me clarify a bit on my particular situation. I have to (because I am using a web framework which handle page transition with ajax, and it is not jquery mobile) ajax load a section into the document. In the section there is my map container which have width and height specified. I have to make sure the map-container has proper dimensions before initiate the google map script. Sadly the framework doesn't have callback for load event :(  ]

Comment: Use the success callback of the ajax request, then select all loadable elements (images, iframes, etc) within the new content and bind to their load events. when they all complete, it's done. This usually isn't a problem because you usually don't care about the width/height of the container.

Comment: Re your update: then you need to be more specific about how the container is added. And btw why not tag your question with the framework you're using?

Answer (score 1):

The google.maps.event object exposes an `addListener()` methods to be able to attach a handler to certain events in the map. You might want to listen on the `tilesloaded' or 'resize' event.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(yourMapObject, 'tilesloaded', yourHandlerFunction);
```

Here is a reference to all events:  http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_events/map_events.html

Answer (score 0):

The window or document events (ready, onload) don't wait for asynchronous ajax calls, so what you are experiencing is the expected behavior.

The usual way to deal with such issues is to bind a callback or promises to your ajax code. For a more specific answer we'd need to see the code you have so far.